# updatePickerInput does not respond to reactive data

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shinywidgets

I am putting together an Shiny app to allow users to upload an area of interest (AOI), and calculate the amount of overlap with an administrative boundary (WMU).  Everything is working as desired, except that my picker input options do not update.  The picker input works, but I would like the choices to only include the WMU that overlap the AOI instead of all possible WMU.  I can calculate the WMU ID that should populate the list, shown in the "TEST_TEXT"output below the map frame, but cannot successfully update the pickerInput.  This [kmz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_NEBT5RXXLZcFvkL1C2fTpANG4u2X7DG/view?usp=sharing) will overlap the several WMU that are loaded at the beginning of the script included below:

```
library(shiny)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(bcdata)
library(shinyjs)
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(DT)
library(pals)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinymanager)




WMU_DATA <-
  bcdc_get_data("wildlife-management-units") %>% st_transform(4326) %>% mutate(Total.WMU.HA =
                                                                                 as.numeric(st_area(.)) / 10000)



##### UI #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML(
      ".shiny-notification {
              height: 100px;
              width: 400px;
              position:fixed;
              top: calc(25% - 50px);;
              left: calc(50% - 200px);;
            }
           "
    )
  )),
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Calculate Overlap With WMU"),
  
  # Inputs
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 3,
      
      textInput(
        inputId = "AOI_NAME",
        label = "AOI Name",
        value = NULL
      ),
      HTML("<br><br>"),
      fileInput(
        inputId = "KMZ",
        label = "Choose KMZ",
        multiple = FALSE,
        accept = c('.kmz')
      ),
      h3("or"),
      HTML("<br><br>"),
      fileInput(
        inputId = "SHAPEFILE",
        label = "Choose shapefile",
        multiple = TRUE,
        accept = c('.shp', '.dbf', '.sbn', '.sbx', '.shx', '.prj', '.xml')
      ),
      
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "WMU_FILTER",
        label = "Filter Overlapping WMU",
        choices = unique(WMU_DATA$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID),
        selected = unique(WMU_DATA$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      
      HTML("<br><br>")
      
      
    ),
    
    # Display OUtputs
    mainPanel(
      width = 9,
      leafletOutput("OVERLAP_MAP", height = 750),
      h3(textOutput("TEST_TEXT")),
      DTOutput("AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE")
    )
  )
)



######server#####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  
  ####reactive data
  
  AOI <-
    reactive({
      if (is.null(input$SHAPEFILE) & !is.null(input$KMZ)) {
        st_read(unzip(input$KMZ$datapath)) %>%
          st_zm(drop = T) %>%
          mutate(AOI_NAME = input$AOI_NAME) %>%
          st_transform(4326) %>%
          select(-Name)
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$SHAPEFILE) & is.null(input$KMZ)) {
        SHAPEFILE()
      }
      else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
  
  WMU_OVERLAP <- reactive({
    st_filter(WMU_DATA, AOI())
  })
  
  AOI_WMU_INTERSECT <-
    reactive({
      st_intersection(AOI(), WMU_OVERLAP()) %>%
        mutate(`HA of Overlap` = round(as.numeric(st_area(.)) / 10000, 0)) %>%
        mutate(`Percent of WMU` = round(`HA of Overlap` / `Total.WMU.HA` *
                                             100, 2))
    })
  
  
  observeEvent(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT
               ,
               {
                 updatePickerInput(
                   session,
                   "WMU_FILTER",
                   choices =  unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID),
                   selected =   unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
                 )
               },
               ignoreInit = TRUE,
               ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  
  ###outputs
  
  
  output$OVERLAP_MAP <-
    renderLeaflet({
      withProgress(message = "Calcualting Overlap", detail = "Should be done soon", {
        AOI_SPATIAL <- AOI() %>% mutate(AOI_NAME = input$AOI_NAME)
        
        WMU <-
          WMU_OVERLAP() %>% filter(WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID %in% input$WMU_FILTER)
        
        Overlap <-
          AOI_WMU_INTERSECT() %>% filter(WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID %in% input$WMU_FILTER)
        
        MAP <-
          
          mapview(
            Overlap,
            zcol = "WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID",
            alpha.regions = 0.2,
            map.types = c("Esri.WorldTopoMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"),
            col.regions = alphabet(nlevels(
              as.factor(WMU$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
            ))
          ) +
          mapview(
            WMU,
            
            zcol = "WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID",
            alpha.regions = 0.2,
            lwd = 3,
            col.regions = alphabet(nlevels(
              as.factor(WMU$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
            )),
            hide = TRUE
          ) +
          mapview(AOI_SPATIAL,
                  label = "AOI_NAME",
                  col.regions = "red")
        MAP@map %>%
          setView(st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_as_sfc(
            st_bbox(AOI_SPATIAL)
          )))[, 1],
          st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_as_sfc(
            st_bbox(AOI_SPATIAL)
          )))[, 2],
          zoom = 9) 
      })
    })
  
  
  output$AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE <-
    renderDT({
      AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE <- AOI_WMU_INTERSECT() %>%
        st_drop_geometry()
      
      AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE
      
    }, filter = "top", extensions = c("FixedHeader", "Buttons"),
    
    options = list(
      pageLength = 100,
      fixedHeader = TRUE,
      dom = "Bfrtip",
      buttons = c('colvis', 'copy', 'excel', 'csv')
    ))
  
  output$TEST_TEXT <-
    renderText(unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID))
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting some `req()` and changing `observeEvent()` to `observe()` makes it work.  Try this

```
######server#####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ####reactive data
  AOI <-
    reactive({
      if (is.null(input$SHAPEFILE) & !is.null(input$KMZ)) {
        st_read(unzip(input$KMZ$datapath)) %>%
          st_zm(drop = T) %>%
          mutate(AOI_NAME = input$AOI_NAME) %>%
          st_transform(4326) %>%
          select(-Name)
      }
      else if (!is.null(input$SHAPEFILE) & is.null(input$KMZ)) {
        SHAPEFILE()
      }
      else{
        return(NULL)
      }
    })
  
  WMU_OVERLAP <- reactive({
    req(AOI())
    st_filter(WMU_DATA, AOI())
  })
  
  AOI_WMU_INTERSECT <-
    reactive({
      req(AOI(), WMU_OVERLAP())
      st_intersection(AOI(), WMU_OVERLAP()) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(`HA of Overlap` = round(as.numeric(st_area(.)) / 10000, 0)) %>%
        dplyr::mutate(`Percent of WMU` = round(`HA of Overlap` / `Total.WMU.HA` *100, 2))
    })
  
  
  observe({updatePickerInput(
                   session,
                   "WMU_FILTER",
                   choices =  unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID),
                   selected =   unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
                 )
               } )#, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  
  
  ###outputs
  
  
  output$OVERLAP_MAP <-
    renderLeaflet({
      req(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT())
      withProgress(message = "Calcualting Overlap", detail = "Should be done soon", {
        AOI_SPATIAL <- AOI() %>% dplyr::mutate(AOI_NAME = input$AOI_NAME)
        
        WMU <-
          WMU_OVERLAP() %>% dplyr::filter(WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID %in% input$WMU_FILTER)
        
        Overlap <-
          AOI_WMU_INTERSECT() %>% dplyr::filter(WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID %in% input$WMU_FILTER)
        
        MAP <-
          
          mapview(
            Overlap,
            zcol = "WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID",
            alpha.regions = 0.2,
            map.types = c("Esri.WorldTopoMap", "Esri.WorldImagery"),
            col.regions = alphabet(nlevels(
              as.factor(WMU$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
            ))
          ) +
          mapview(
            WMU,
            
            zcol = "WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID",
            alpha.regions = 0.2,
            lwd = 3,
            col.regions = alphabet(nlevels(
              as.factor(WMU$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID)
            )),
            hide = TRUE
          ) +
          mapview(AOI_SPATIAL,
                  label = "AOI_NAME",
                  col.regions = "red")
        MAP@map %>%
          setView(st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_as_sfc(
            st_bbox(AOI_SPATIAL)
          )))[, 1],
          st_coordinates(st_centroid(st_as_sfc(
            st_bbox(AOI_SPATIAL)
          )))[, 2],
          zoom = 9) 
      })
    })
  
  
  output$AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE <-
    renderDT({
      AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE <- AOI_WMU_INTERSECT() %>%  st_drop_geometry()
      
      AOI_OVERLAP_TABLE
      
    }, filter = "top", extensions = c("FixedHeader", "Buttons"),
    
    options = list(
      pageLength = 100,
      fixedHeader = TRUE,
      dom = "Bfrtip",
      buttons = c('colvis', 'copy', 'excel', 'csv')
    ))
  
  output$TEST_TEXT <- renderText(unique(AOI_WMU_INTERSECT()$WILDLIFE_MGMT_UNIT_ID))
}
```

Comment: I had tried it using only observe and that did not work, I'm assuming this one works because it enforces and "order of operation" to the script?

Comment: Otherwise, it will be random order.